# Saving Gradle Dependencies to a Directory

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

How can I save all the dependent jars for a module to a directory?  I have an application that runs in IntelliJ IDEA, but I want to run it on another computer so I need to copy all the JAR files there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, please consider using Gradle (or Gradle Wrapper) to do such things like getting/downloading dependencies of a project on another computer. But if you need to copy dependencies for any other reason you can define a task similar to:

```
task copyDependencies(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.runtime
    into "lib"
}
```

When you run:

```
gradle copyDependencies
```

runtime dependencies will be copied to a `lib/` folder.

#### Example

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.11'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.9.1'
    compile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.4.196'

    testCompile group: 'org.spockframework', name: 'spock-core', version: '1.1-groovy-2.4'

}
task copyDependencies(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.runtime
    into "lib"
}
```

Command:

```
gradle copyDependencies
```

And `lib/` directory contains:

```
lib
├── groovy-all-2.3.11.jar
├── h2-1.4.196.jar
└── jackson-core-2.9.1.jar
```

### Use Gradle Wrapper

As I mentioned earlier, please consider using [Gradle Wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) so you don't have to worry about if there is a Gradle distribution installed on another computer. As stated [in the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#sec:wrapper_generation) you can easily add Gradle Wrapper and then you can run

```
./gradlew [task]
```

by using wrapper instead of Gradle installed on your OS. In your case running

```
./gradlew build
```

will download all dependencies and build the project. It's way better than copying dependencies manually, Gradle was invented to do it for us.

Comment: First of all, the answer is perfectly fine. But I really do not get why people continue to use such complicated paths like `${project.projectDir}/lib`. The default functionality of any Gradle task interprets paths relative to the project directory, so `lib` would be enough.

Comment: @lu.koerfer You're right, thanks for the input! Example updated.

Comment: Also, why IT depends on `build`?

Comment: Doesn't it need `configurations.compileClasspath` instead of `configurations.runtime` ?

Comment: Hi @SzymonStepniak, i am getting following error "Could not get unknown property 'compileClasspath' for configuration container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfigurationContainer."

Comment: I have to write following lines which solved this issue configurations.implementation.setCanBeResolved(true)
configurations.api.setCanBeResolved(true)
task copyDependencies(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.implementation
    into "libs"
//    include 'com.allegion.**'
}

Comment: This fails with `Cannot choose between the following variants of project` if you have more than one buildType

Comment: Is that the reason to downvote the answer that may not fit a unique edge case?

Answer (score 4):

following solution worked for me

```
configurations.implementation.setCanBeResolved(true) 
configurations.api.setCanBeResolved(true)
task copyDependencies(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.implementation  
    into "libs" 
}
```

Comment: ```

task copyDependencies(type: Copy) {
    configurations.implementation.setCanBeResolved(true)
    from configurations.implementation
    into "lib"
}

```
This is what worked for me